# is there any boxing in this code?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, entity-framework

I have the project (by using EntityFramework) with 2 solution,in one of them i have this code:

```
   try
        {
            var context = new SabzNegar01Entities1();

            int count = 0;

            count = (from p in context.tbl_Stock
                     select p).Count();

            if (count != 0)
            {
                var objectList = (from p in context.tbl_Stock
                                  select p).ToList();


            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error in Reading  Stocks Data");
        }
```

in this part:

```
 var objectList = (from p in context.tbl_Stock select p).ToList();
```

is any boxing happend?if yes is there another way because i don't want have boxing?
i can't see tbl_Stock in another solution then i can't use:

```
 IList<tbl_Stock> objectList = (from p in context.tbl_Stock  select p).ToList();
```

how can i sent the result to another soltion?
can i store this list in a DataTable or DataSet?

Comment: open ildasm and check...C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\ildasm.exe

Answer (score 4):

There is almost no difference between using `var` and `IList<tbl_Stock>` there. And using `var` definitely does not cause boxing to happen.

I don't see any boxing in your code, but you can try to decompile it into IL and look for `box`/`unbox` instructions.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ is a variable of type IEnumerable, and objectList is a variable of type IList.

var & IList is SAME here.

Compiling is from right to left, and var will be replaced with IList at last.